# How to bundle 5 PDF ebooks into 1 file for download

Tags: pdf

How to bundle 5 PDF ebooks into 1 file for download

I have 5 PDF eBooks that I sell  I want to have these 5 PDF file into 1 file

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do so by using sites like ilovepdf.com and combinepdf.com. They are very straightforward to use and there will instructions. But if you have trouble, please leave a comment below.

Answer (score 1):

It depends from what you want to do. If the files should be separated, the best option is to zip them and send the zip file; the buyer will unzip them. Otherwise there are programs which merge many input files. I use PDFsam basic (https://pdfsam.org), but there are many alternatives: check https://alternativeto.net/software/pdfsam/ .